# Slow query in MariaDB-10.5.15, fetching time, with a simple select

Tags: mariadb

I'm having a problem with a slow query in MariaDB, which is driving me crazy, and it's X-file worthy.

I have a simple table, which I show you below, with only 10 rows, and the time it takes to return a simple `select * from the table` is more than 180 seconds !!!!

I provide the following data to see if you see something strange and you can help me:

a) The structure of the table, to highlight the mediumblog field where an image is saved.

b) mysql `slow_query` output.

c) Global variables.

**a) Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `clientespendientes` (
  `numeroid` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Número de DNI o pasaporte del cliente',
  `direccionpublica` blob NOT NULL COMMENT 'Dirección pública del cliente',
  `email` varchar(101) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Email del usuario',
  `documento` mediumblob NOT NULL COMMENT 'DNI o Pasaporte del Cliente',
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Momento en el que creó la petición de verificación',
  `nacionalidad` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Nacionalidad Cliente',
  `idioma` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Idioma de cara al envío de mails',
  `ip` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Ip desde la que se dio de alta el cliente',
  `nombrefichero` varchar(30) DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Nombre del fichero con el que debemos devolver la clave pública',
  PRIMARY KEY (`numeroid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Clientes pendientes de verificar'
```

**b) mysql slow query output**

```
Time: 220719 23:46:08
 User@Host: cabe[cabe] @  [217.61.225.227]
 Thread_id: 33  Schema: litra  QC_hit: No
 **Query_time: 179.691794**  Lock_time: 0.000120  Rows_sent: 10  Rows_examined: 10
 Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 5504314
 Full_scan: Yes  Full_join: No  Tmp_table: No  Tmp_table_on_disk: No
 Filesort: No  Filesort_on_disk: No  Merge_passes: 0  Priority_queue: No

 explain: id   select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    r_rows  filtered        r_filtered      Extra
 explain: 1    SIMPLE  clientespendientes      ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10      10.00   100.00  100.00

SET timestamp=1658274368;
SELECT * FROM litra.clientespendientes
LIMIT 0, 1000;
```

**c) Global variables.**

```
analyze_sample_percentage       100.000000
aria_block_size 8192
aria_checkpoint_interval        30
aria_checkpoint_log_activity    1048576
aria_encrypt_tables     OFF
aria_force_start_after_recovery_failures        0
aria_group_commit       none
aria_group_commit_interval      0
aria_log_file_size      1073741824
aria_log_purge_type     immediate
aria_max_sort_file_size 9223372036853727232
aria_page_checksum      ON
aria_pagecache_age_threshold    300
aria_pagecache_buffer_size      134217728
aria_pagecache_division_limit   100
aria_pagecache_file_hash_size   512
aria_recover_options    BACKUP,QUICK
aria_repair_threads     1
aria_sort_buffer_size   268434432
aria_stats_method       nulls_unequal
aria_sync_log_dir       NEWFILE
aria_used_for_temp_tables       ON
auto_increment_increment        1
auto_increment_offset   1
autocommit      ON
automatic_sp_privileges ON
back_log        80
basedir /usr
big_tables      OFF
bind_address    0.0.0.0
binlog_annotate_row_events      ON
binlog_cache_size       32768
binlog_checksum CRC32
binlog_commit_wait_count        0
binlog_commit_wait_usec 100000
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF
binlog_file_cache_size  16384
binlog_format   MIXED
binlog_optimize_thread_scheduling       ON
binlog_row_image        FULL
binlog_row_metadata     NO_LOG
binlog_stmt_cache_size  32768
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection        utf8
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem        binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    utf8mb4
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir      /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
check_constraint_checks ON
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database      utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_server        utf8mb4_general_ci
column_compression_threshold    100
column_compression_zlib_level   6
column_compression_zlib_strategy        DEFAULT_STRATEGY
column_compression_zlib_wrap    OFF
completion_type NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert       AUTO
connect_timeout 10
core_file       OFF
datadir /var/lib/mysql/
date_format     %Y-%m-%d
datetime_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
deadlock_search_depth_long      15
deadlock_search_depth_short     4
deadlock_timeout_long   50000000
deadlock_timeout_short  10000
debug_no_thread_alarm   OFF
default_master_connection
default_password_lifetime       0
default_regex_flags
default_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine
default_week_format     0
delay_key_write ON
delayed_insert_limit    100
delayed_insert_timeout  300
delayed_queue_size      1000
disconnect_on_expired_password  OFF
div_precision_increment 4
encrypt_binlog  OFF
encrypt_tmp_disk_tables OFF
encrypt_tmp_files       OFF
enforce_storage_engine
eq_range_index_dive_limit       200
error_count     0
event_scheduler OFF
expensive_subquery_limit        100
expire_logs_days        10
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp OFF
external_user
extra_max_connections   1
extra_port      0
flush   OFF
flush_time      0
foreign_key_checks      ON
ft_boolean_syntax       + -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len 84
ft_min_word_len 4
ft_query_expansion_limit        20
ft_stopword_file        (built-in)
general_log     ON
general_log_file        /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
group_concat_max_len    1048576
gtid_binlog_pos
gtid_binlog_state
gtid_cleanup_batch_size 64
gtid_current_pos
gtid_domain_id  0
gtid_ignore_duplicates  OFF
gtid_pos_auto_engines
gtid_seq_no     0
gtid_slave_pos
gtid_strict_mode        OFF
have_compress   YES
have_crypt      YES
have_dynamic_loading    YES
have_geometry   YES
have_openssl    YES
have_profiling  YES
have_query_cache        YES
have_rtree_keys YES
have_ssl        DISABLED
have_symlink    YES
histogram_size  254
histogram_type  DOUBLE_PREC_HB
host_cache_size 279
hostname        Litra0
identity        0
idle_readonly_transaction_timeout       0
idle_transaction_timeout        0
idle_write_transaction_timeout  0
ignore_builtin_innodb   OFF
ignore_db_dirs
in_predicate_conversion_threshold       1000
in_transaction  0
init_connect
init_file
init_slave
innodb_adaptive_flushing        ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm    10.000000
innodb_adaptive_hash_index      OFF
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts        8
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 0
innodb_autoextend_increment     64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode        1
innodb_background_scrub_data_check_interval     0
innodb_background_scrub_data_compressed OFF
innodb_background_scrub_data_interval   0
innodb_background_scrub_data_uncompressed       OFF
innodb_buf_dump_status_frequency        0
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size   134217728
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown     ON
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now     OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct     25
innodb_buffer_pool_filename     ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    1
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup      ON
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now     OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size 1073741824
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25
innodb_change_buffering none
innodb_checksum_algorithm       full_crc32
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled    OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency       0
innodb_compression_algorithm    zlib
innodb_compression_default      OFF
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct        5
innodb_compression_level        6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max  50
innodb_concurrency_tickets      0
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir
innodb_deadlock_detect  ON
innodb_default_encryption_key_id        1
innodb_default_row_format       dynamic
innodb_defragment       OFF
innodb_defragment_fill_factor   0.900000
innodb_defragment_fill_factor_n_recs    20
innodb_defragment_frequency     40
innodb_defragment_n_pages       7
innodb_defragment_stats_accuracy        0
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache  OFF
innodb_disallow_writes  OFF
innodb_doublewrite      ON
innodb_encrypt_log      OFF
innodb_encrypt_tables   OFF
innodb_encrypt_temporary_tables OFF
innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age        1
innodb_encryption_rotation_iops 100
innodb_encryption_threads       0
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_fatal_semaphore_wait_threshold   600
innodb_file_format
innodb_file_per_table   ON
innodb_fill_factor      100
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout     1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  1
innodb_flush_method     fsync
innodb_flush_neighbors  1
innodb_flush_sync       ON
innodb_flushing_avg_loops       30
innodb_force_load_corrupted     OFF
innodb_force_primary_key        OFF
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_ft_aux_table
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print     OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword       ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size        84
innodb_ft_min_token_size        3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize     2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree       2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size      640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table
innodb_immediate_scrub_data_uncompressed        OFF
innodb_instant_alter_column_allowed     add_drop_reorder
innodb_io_capacity      200
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000
innodb_large_prefix
innodb_lock_schedule_algorithm  fcfs
innodb_lock_wait_timeout        50
innodb_lock_wait_timeout        50
innodb_log_buffer_size  16777216
innodb_log_checksums    ON
innodb_log_compressed_pages     ON
innodb_log_file_size    100663296
innodb_log_files_in_group       1
innodb_log_group_home_dir       ./
innodb_log_optimize_ddl OFF
innodb_log_write_ahead_size     8192
innodb_lru_flush_size   32
innodb_lru_scan_depth   1536
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct      90.000000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  0.000000
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay      0
innodb_max_purge_lag_wait       4294967295
innodb_max_undo_log_size        10485760
innodb_monitor_disable
innodb_monitor_enable
innodb_monitor_reset
innodb_monitor_reset_all
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size        134217728
innodb_open_files       2000
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only   OFF
innodb_page_cleaners    1
innodb_page_size        16384
innodb_prefix_index_cluster_optimization        OFF
innodb_print_all_deadlocks      OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size 300
innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency    128
innodb_purge_threads    4
innodb_random_read_ahead        OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold     56
innodb_read_io_threads  4
innodb_read_only        OFF
innodb_replication_delay        0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout      OFF
innodb_scrub_log        OFF
innodb_scrub_log_speed  256
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay  4
innodb_stats_auto_recalc        ON
innodb_stats_include_delete_marked      OFF
innodb_stats_method     nulls_equal
innodb_stats_modified_counter   0
innodb_stats_on_metadata        OFF
innodb_stats_persistent ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages    20
innodb_stats_traditional        ON
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages     8
innodb_status_output    OFF
innodb_status_output_locks      OFF
innodb_strict_mode      ON
innodb_sync_array_size  1
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30
innodb_table_locks      ON
innodb_temp_data_file_path      ibtmp1:12M:autoextend
innodb_thread_concurrency       0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay       0
innodb_tmpdir
innodb_undo_directory   ./
innodb_undo_log_truncate        OFF
innodb_undo_logs        128
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0
innodb_use_atomic_writes        ON
innodb_use_native_aio   ON
innodb_version  10.5.15
innodb_write_io_threads 4
insert_id       0
interactive_timeout     28800
join_buffer_size        262144
join_buffer_space_limit 2097152
join_cache_level        2
keep_files_on_create    OFF
key_buffer_size 268435456
key_cache_age_threshold 300
key_cache_block_size    1024
key_cache_division_limit        100
key_cache_file_hash_size        512
key_cache_segments      0
large_files_support     ON
large_page_size 0
large_pages     OFF
last_gtid
last_insert_id  0
lc_messages     en_US
lc_messages_dir /usr/share/mysql
lc_time_names   en_US
license GPL
local_infile    ON
lock_wait_timeout       86400
locked_in_memory        OFF
log_bin OFF
log_bin_basename
log_bin_compress        OFF
log_bin_compress_min_len        256
log_bin_index
log_bin_trust_function_creators OFF
log_disabled_statements sp
log_error       /var/log/mysql/error.log
log_output      FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes   OFF
log_slave_updates       OFF
log_slow_admin_statements       ON
log_slow_disabled_statements    sp
log_slow_filter admin,filesort,filesort_on_disk,filesort_priority_queue,full_join,full_scan,query_cache,query_cache_miss,tmp_table,tmp_table_on_disk
log_slow_rate_limit     1
log_slow_slave_statements       ON
log_slow_verbosity      query_plan,explain
log_tc_size     24576
log_warnings    2
long_query_time 10.000000
low_priority_updates    OFF
lower_case_file_system  OFF
lower_case_table_names  0
master_verify_checksum  OFF
max_allowed_packet      1073741824
max_binlog_cache_size   18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size 1073741824
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size      18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors      100
max_connections 151
max_delayed_threads     20
max_digest_length       1024
max_error_count 64
max_heap_table_size     16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads      20
max_join_size   18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data        1024
max_password_errors     4294967295
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382
max_recursive_iterations        4294967295
max_relay_log_size      1073741824
max_rowid_filter_size   131072
max_seeks_for_key       4294967295
max_session_mem_used    9223372036854775807
max_rowid_filter_size   131072
max_seeks_for_key       4294967295
max_session_mem_used    9223372036854775807
max_sort_length 1024
max_sp_recursion_depth  0
max_statement_time      0.000000
max_tmp_tables  32
max_user_connections    0
max_write_lock_count    4294967295
metadata_locks_cache_size       1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances   8
min_examined_row_limit  0
mrr_buffer_size 262144
myisam_block_size       1024
myisam_data_pointer_size        6
myisam_max_sort_file_size       9223372036853727232
myisam_mmap_size        18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options  BACKUP,QUICK
myisam_repair_threads   1
myisam_sort_buffer_size 134216704
myisam_stats_method     NULLS_UNEQUAL
myisam_use_mmap OFF
mysql56_temporal_format ON
net_buffer_length       16384
net_read_timeout        30
net_retry_count 10
net_write_timeout       60
old     OFF
old_alter_table DEFAULT
old_mode
old_passwords   OFF
open_files_limit        32194
optimizer_max_sel_arg_weight    32000
optimizer_prune_level   1
optimizer_search_depth  62
optimizer_selectivity_sampling_limit    100
optimizer_switch        index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_cond>
optimizer_trace enabled=off
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size    1048576
optimizer_use_condition_selectivity     4
performance_schema      OFF
performance_schema_accounts_size        -1
performance_schema_digests_size -1
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size      -1
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size   -1
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size  -1
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size  -1
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size       -1
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size        -1
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size     -1
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size       -1
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size    -1
performance_schema_hosts_size   -1
performance_schema_max_cond_classes     90
performance_schema_max_cond_instances   -1
performance_schema_max_digest_length    1024
performance_schema_max_file_classes     80
performance_schema_max_file_handles     32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances   -1
performance_schema_max_index_stat       -1
performance_schema_max_memory_classes   320
performance_schema_max_metadata_locks   -1
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes    210
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instances    -1
performance_schema_max_program_instances        -1
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes   50
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances -1
performance_schema_max_socket_classes   10
performance_schema_max_socket_instances -1
performance_schema_max_sql_text_length  1024
performance_schema_max_stage_classes    160
performance_schema_max_statement_classes        222
performance_schema_max_statement_stack  10
performance_schema_max_table_handles    -1
performance_schema_max_table_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat  -1
performance_schema_max_thread_classes   50
performance_schema_max_thread_instances -1
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size   -1
performance_schema_setup_actors_size    -1
performance_schema_setup_objects_size   -1
performance_schema_users_size   -1
pid_file        /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
plugin_dir      /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/
plugin_maturity gamma
port    3306
preload_buffer_size     32768
profiling       OFF
profiling_history_size  15
progress_report_time    5
protocol_version        10
proxy_protocol_networks
proxy_user
pseudo_slave_mode       OFF
pseudo_thread_id        37
query_alloc_block_size  16384
query_cache_limit       1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit        4096
query_cache_size        1048576
query_cache_strip_comments      OFF
query_cache_type        OFF
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF
query_prealloc_size     24576
rand_seed1      338934328
rand_seed2      991539275
range_alloc_block_size  4096
read_binlog_speed_limit 0
read_buffer_size        131072
read_only       OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size    262144
relay_log
relay_log_basename
relay_log_index
relay_log_info_file     relay-log.info
relay_log_purge ON
relay_log_recovery      OFF
relay_log_space_limit   0
replicate_annotate_row_events   ON
replicate_do_db
replicate_do_table
replicate_events_marked_for_skip        REPLICATE
replicate_ignore_db
replicate_ignore_table
replicate_wild_do_table
replicate_wild_ignore_table
report_host
report_password
report_port     3306
report_user
require_secure_transport        OFF
rowid_merge_buff_size   8388608
rpl_semi_sync_master_enabled    OFF
rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout    10000
rpl_semi_sync_master_trace_level        32
rpl_semi_sync_master_wait_no_slave      ON
rpl_semi_sync_master_wait_point AFTER_COMMIT
rpl_semi_sync_master_wait_point AFTER_COMMIT
rpl_semi_sync_slave_delay_master        OFF
rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled     OFF
rpl_semi_sync_slave_kill_conn_timeout   5
rpl_semi_sync_slave_trace_level 32
secure_auth     ON
secure_file_priv
secure_timestamp        NO
server_id       1
session_track_schema    ON
session_track_state_change      OFF
session_track_system_variables  autocommit,character_set_client,character_set_connection,character_set_results,time_zone
session_track_transaction_info  OFF
skip_external_locking   ON
skip_name_resolve       OFF
skip_networking OFF
skip_parallel_replication       OFF
skip_replication        OFF
skip_show_database      OFF
slave_compressed_protocol       OFF
slave_ddl_exec_mode     IDEMPOTENT
slave_domain_parallel_threads   0
slave_exec_mode STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir       /tmp
slave_max_allowed_packet        1073741824
slave_net_timeout       60
slave_parallel_max_queued       131072
slave_parallel_mode     optimistic
slave_parallel_threads  0
slave_parallel_workers  0
slave_run_triggers_for_rbr      NO
slave_skip_errors       OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum       ON
slave_transaction_retries       10
slave_transaction_retry_errors  1158,1159,1160,1161,1205,1213,1429,2013,12701
slave_transaction_retry_interval        0
slave_type_conversions
slow_launch_time        2
slow_query_log  ON
slow_query_log_file     /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
socket  /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
sort_buffer_size        2097152
sql_auto_is_null        OFF
sql_big_selects ON
sql_buffer_result       OFF
sql_if_exists   OFF
sql_if_exists   OFF
sql_log_bin     ON
sql_log_off     OFF
sql_mode        STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_notes       ON
sql_quote_show_create   ON
sql_safe_updates        OFF
sql_select_limit        18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter  0
sql_warnings    OFF
ssl_ca
ssl_capath
ssl_cert
ssl_cipher
ssl_crl
ssl_crlpath
ssl_key
standard_compliant_cte  ON
storage_engine  InnoDB
stored_program_cache    256
strict_password_validation      ON
sync_binlog     0
sync_frm        ON
sync_master_info        10000
sync_relay_log  10000
sync_relay_log_info     10000
system_time_zone        UTC
system_versioning_alter_history ERROR
system_versioning_asof  DEFAULT
table_definition_cache  400
table_open_cache        2000
table_open_cache_instances      8
tcp_keepalive_interval  0
tcp_keepalive_probes    0
tcp_keepalive_time      0
tcp_nodelay     ON
thread_cache_size       151
thread_handling one-thread-per-connection
thread_pool_dedicated_listener  OFF
thread_pool_exact_stats OFF
thread_pool_idle_timeout        60
thread_pool_max_threads 65536
thread_pool_oversubscribe       3
thread_pool_prio_kickup_timer   1000
thread_pool_priority    auto
thread_pool_prio_kickup_timer   1000
thread_pool_priority    auto
thread_pool_size        12
thread_pool_stall_limit 500
thread_stack    196608
time_format     %H:%i:%s
time_zone       SYSTEM
timestamp       1658275075.187231
tls_version     TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
tmp_disk_table_size     18446744073709551615
tmp_memory_table_size   16777216
tmp_table_size  16777216
tmpdir  /tmp
transaction_alloc_block_size    8192
transaction_prealloc_size       4096
tx_isolation    REPEATABLE-READ
tx_read_only    OFF
unique_checks   ON
updatable_views_with_limit      YES
use_stat_tables PREFERABLY_FOR_QUERIES
userstat        OFF
version 10.5.15-MariaDB-0+deb11u1-log
version_comment Debian 11
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os      debian-linux-gnu
version_malloc_library  system
version_source_revision 9aa3564e8a06c3d2027fc514213ecf42b049b06e
version_ssl_library     OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
wait_timeout    28800
warning_count   0
wsrep_osu_method        TOI
wsrep_sr_store  table
wsrep_auto_increment_control    ON
wsrep_causal_reads      OFF
wsrep_certification_rules       strict
wsrep_certify_nonpk     ON
wsrep_cluster_address
wsrep_cluster_name      my_wsrep_cluster
wsrep_convert_lock_to_trx       OFF
wsrep_data_home_dir     /var/lib/mysql/
wsrep_dbug_option
wsrep_debug     NONE
wsrep_desync    OFF
wsrep_dirty_reads       OFF
wsrep_drupal_282555_workaround  OFF
wsrep_forced_binlog_format      NONE
wsrep_gtid_domain_id    0
wsrep_gtid_mode OFF
wsrep_gtid_seq_no       0
wsrep_ignore_apply_errors       7
wsrep_load_data_splitting       OFF
wsrep_log_conflicts     OFF
wsrep_max_ws_rows       0
wsrep_max_ws_size       2147483647
wsrep_mysql_replication_bundle  0
wsrep_node_address
wsrep_node_incoming_address     AUTO
wsrep_node_name Litra0
wsrep_notify_cmd
wsrep_on        OFF
wsrep_patch_version     wsrep_26.22
wsrep_provider  none
wsrep_provider_options
wsrep_recover   OFF
wsrep_reject_queries    NONE
wsrep_replicate_myisam  OFF
wsrep_restart_slave     OFF
wsrep_retry_autocommit  1
wsrep_slave_fk_checks   ON
wsrep_slave_uk_checks   OFF
wsrep_slave_threads     1
wsrep_sst_auth
wsrep_sst_donor
wsrep_sst_donor_rejects_queries OFF
wsrep_sst_method        rsync
wsrep_sst_receive_address       AUTO
wsrep_start_position    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
wsrep_strict_ddl        OFF
wsrep_sync_wait 0
wsrep_trx_fragment_size 0
wsrep_trx_fragment_unit bytes
```

Comment: is just `select docmento` instead of `select *` just as slow?  is `select numeroid,direccionpublica,email,fecha,nacionalidad,idioma,ip,nombrefichero` fast or slow?

Comment: The result set is over 5M. Do you need the blob field for all 10 records?

Comment: select documento instead of select *   -> continues slow  189.02 seg

Comment: SELECT numeroid,direccionpublica,email,fecha,nacionalidad,idioma,ip,nombrefichero FROM litra.clientespendientes;    -> FAST 0.062 seg

Comment: Yes is a little over than 5M. The blob field is necesary

Comment: Odd. Your variables show your server is mariadb. See version set to 10.5.15-MariaDB-0+deb11u1-lo. Are you sure you are using mysql 8? Did you take the data dir from mariadb and run it in mysql 8. You can run explain analyze to see which parts of your query are slow.

Comment: Looks like your client collation and charset are different to the server, that is utf8_general_ci vs utf8mb4_general_ci, likely its doing a conversion from charset and collation 4 bytes at a time for your strings. Maybe try setting charset and collation to match on your client

Comment: Since you have to fetch the blob field and it takes a lot of time, so please consider Not store blobs to mysql. We can upload the actual file through a cdn service, and  store a cdn resource url in DB like xxx.mp4 I think this is a common solution

Comment: Does `innodb_io_capacity` represent the amount of IOPs on the server? Are you out of memory and MariaDB is being swapped during the running of the query? Is your IO usage saturated?

Comment: @abdollar I have change the collation, and continues slow. 216 seg.   `code`  +----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+`code`

Comment: @danblack I have change innodb_io_capacity , and the problem continues. I show the new values:   +------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| innodb_io_capacity     | 2000  |
| innodb_io_capacity_max | 3000  |
+------------------------+-------+

Comment: @wuhoyt you are right, I am going to resolve the problem storing the mediumblob data outside mysql,  only saving the path of the file inside. I did not know mysql was too slow working with blob fields.  Thanks to all